# SQL Injection and multiline comments

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-injection

I was testing a clients' queries and came across an interesting question. Could a bad intentioned hacker SQL inject the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1
AND cfield='0'
AND (
field1 like '%$searchterm%' OR
field2 like '%$searchterm%' OR
)
```

For example, to my mind, there's no way he can comment out what's after the first $searchterm, and just insert other queries:

```
field1 like '%$searchterm%'
```

Still, I may be wrong. Looking forward to your opinions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $searchterm concatenated on the server ? It _looks_ like PHP.

Comment: No concatenation whatsoever. Whatever is entered in the search input, gets inserted there. There is no sanitization in place.

Comment: I'd say that's a resounding "Yes"

Comment: Queries are not safe or vulnerable. What counts is the mechanism you use to feed param values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is PHP and I will apply some sanitization.

Comment: @Kyprulez:if you're using oracle ,then read this article might help you in preventing sql injections [sanitize your input ](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
searchterm = "');drop table customers;SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ( field1 like '"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. I will just be careful with sanitizing the inputs before such injections ruin anything.

Comment: There's no need to sanitize anything. Just use prepared statements.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1
AND cfield='0'
AND (
field1 like '%' || :searchterm || '%' OR
field2 like '%' || :searchterm || '%' OR
)
```

... where `:searchterm` is an input parameter filled in whateter function your favourite language offers.

Comment: Oh great, got your point! This is very useful as well. Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct approach.  Marlin gets upvoted for a nice graphic example